# Calling a common function across multiple files in a directory in Python

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I have a python project with the following structure

```
- my-project/
  - my_project/
    - __init__.py
    - modules_charts/
      - chart_a.py
      - chart_b.py
      - ...
    - main.py
  - poetry.lock
  - pyproject.toml
  - README.md
```

My goal is to have a dynamic `modules_charts` folder that contain a non-limited list of python files with non-standard naming. Each file contain the same function called `create_chart()`.

I want to be able to call all those `create_chart()` functions from the `main.py` script.

I want to avoid updating `main.py` every time I add a new file within the `modules_charts` folder.

Until now I was using the following code in `main.py`:

```
for file_name in sorted(os.listdir("modules_charts")):
    if not file_name.endswith(".py"):
        continue
    module_name = file_name[:-3]
    module = import_module("." + module_name, package="modules_charts")
    module.main()
```

I have 2 concerns about this working solution:

1. It generates an issue if I am running my script with `python my_project/main.py`
2. There might be another way of doing it by using `import` and `__init__.py`

What would be the proper way to achieve this without taking into account the directory where I am running my script.

Comment: yes look into more about __init__

Comment: Could you please guide me ? I found some answers proposing to add all the name of the files of ```modules_charts/``` to the variable ```__all__``` but then I don't know how to call the function ```create_chart()``` as I don't know the name of those files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely want to use `__init__.py` to help expose sub modules.

**`main.py`**

```py
import inspect
import modules_charts

## call every member's create_chart method
for member in inspect.getmembers(modules_charts, inspect.ismodule):
    getattr(modules_charts, member[0]).create_chart()
```

**`modules_charts/__init__.py`**

```py
## directly expose these modules by name
from . import chart_a
from . import chart_b
```

**`modules_charts/chart_a.py`**

```py
def create_chart():
    print("hello")
```

**`modules_charts/chart_b.py`**

```py
def create_chart():
    print("world")
```

This should give you:

```
hello
world
```

Of course you need to update `__init__.py` when you want to directly expose new charts but that is part of your chart infrastructure so not as big a problem as keeping uses of the charting up to date.

To further simplify `main.py` you might write a method in `__init__.py` to return the modules. Maybe something like:

**`main.py`**

```py
import modules_charts

## call every member's create_chart method
for chart in modules_charts.get_charts():
    chart.create_chart()
```

**`modules_charts/__init__.py`**

```py
import types
from . import chart_a
from . import chart_b

def get_charts():
    for name, value in globals().items():
        if isinstance(value, types.ModuleType) and name != "types":
            yield value
```

That should give you the same result when `main.py` is run.

If you wanted to leverage `__all__` in your module, you can also do this.

**`modules_charts/__init__.py`**

```py
from . import chart_a
from . import chart_b

__all__ = ["chart_a", "chart_b"]
```

That simplifies your module quite a bit, but it might make it a little harder to use it as:

```py
import modules_charts

for chart_name in modules_charts.__all__:
    getattr(modules_charts, chart_name).create_chart()
```

Comment: The thing is that the name of the files within "module_charts/" folder can be random. I want to avoid explicitly calling "modules_charts.chart_a" as I don't know if it will be called "chart_a"

Comment: How do you know what to call if you don't know the name?  Do you want to just call for all of them?

Comment: Yes. I want to call of them. Every python file in this folder will have the same function available and each of them needs to be called

Comment: I get a warning from ruff saying that I should consider using __alll__ instead of unused imports